# How to make a python script a command?

Tags: python, scripts

I'm trying to make a python script into a command, eg: google's ipaddr.py (http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/). I want to be able to type `ipaddr` and it puts out what I want. Is this possible? I've tried making it executable with `chmod +x`, then moving it to `/bin` and it still says:

```
No command 'ipaddr' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ipmaddr' from package 'net-tools' (main)
 Command 'ibaddr' from package 'infiniband-diags' (universe)
ipaddr: command not found
```

Comment: What is  the output of `ls -l /bin/ipmaddr` command?

Comment: Are you familiar with what ipaddr provides? It's not a runnable/script as you appear to be expecting, but a *library* to be used in software (development).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

> Since ipaddr.py is **library** for inspecting and manipulating IP address,
>   the first thing you'll want to do is create some objects. You can use
>   ipaddr to create objects from strings, integers or other ipaddr
>   objects.

Check the following wiki page for examples:

http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/wiki/Using3144

Depending on your needs, installing the python package from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddr/) system wide and creating a python script (to later put in `/usr/bin`) is probably the best option to get a command line utility using **ipaddr**.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with ipaddr, so I can only answer in general, with the title of your question as a starting point:

Looking at the command you use (in your post) you do not use the extension `.py`. If you do not use it in your command, you should remove it from the script itself as well (and make it executable indeed). I looked into the name of the script, it is ipaddr*.py*.

And: if you want to invoke the script outside $PATH, you will have to add the path in your command as well.

***resuming:***

**Running a script outside $PATH:**

Invoking a script *with* language extension -> script name should include extension:

```
    python /path/script_name.py (works if script is either executable or not)
    /path/script_name.py (works only if script is executable, mind the shebang)
```

Invoking a script *without* language extension:

```
    /path/script_name (only if executable, mind the shebang)
```

**Running a script in $PATH** can be done with language extension, but is considered bad practice, so -> script name should not include extension, run it by the command:

```
    script_name (works only if executable, mind the shebang)
```

Of course, before you rename or move a script to another directory, you should make sure the script is not importing anything from the directory where you are moving it from, and the script itself is not invoked by other scripts.

To make it more complicated: *if* the script is part of a more comprehensive structure in its own directory, but you still want to invoke it separately by its name, you can create a link to the script in `~/bin` (`ln-sf`).

So in this particular case: move the script to `~/bin`, make it executable, remove its language extension, log out and in, and run it by its name. That is, *if* the file is / would be a runable script as your question suggests.